# Change indent in standard table of content (not tocloft)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I know that the indenting size of `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` can be changed in `tocloft` package using `\cftsetindents`. I am using a Latex template and I shouldn't use `tocloft` or any other TOC packages. So my question is how can I control those indents in the standard TOC? it's okay if I need to modify the cls files, etc but I don't know what are the settings to be changed.

```
\documentclass[singlespace,tocchapterhead,a4paper,openright,twoside]{MyThesisEnglish}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array}
\citestyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=40mm, right=25mm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\include{Title}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{DEDICATIONS}}
\include{Dedication}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ABSTRACT}}
\include{Abstract}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{\textit{ABSTRACT2}}}
\include{ABSTRACT2}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}}
\include{Acknow}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{APPROVAL}}
\include{Approval}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{DECLARATION}}
\include{Declaration}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother


\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}}
\include{abbrev}


\mainmatter
\singlespace


\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter4}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter5}
\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}
\include{Chapter6}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{REFERENCES/Bibliography}}
\begin{singlespace}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\bibliographystyle{ai}
\end{singlespace}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{APPENDICES}}
\appendix
\include{AppendixA}
\include{AppendixB}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{BIODATA OF STUDENT}}
\include{biodata}                                                %
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{LIST OF PUBLICATIONS}}
\include{listofpublications}                                    %
\end{document}
```

**Update:** I increased the indention for chapter titles using `\setlength\@tempdima{5.5em}` but still couldn't find the way to increase the indention of sections and  subsections. https://imgur.com/a/3lUcG

```
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %   
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip .1cm \@plus \p@ %{the v-distance between the headings in the contents}
    \setlength\@tempdima{5.5em}% %{the distance between the number of the chapter and its title}
    \begingroup
           \parindent\z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance \leftskip \@tempdima 
      \hskip  -\leftskip 
      \etchapterheadstyle{#1}\nobreak
% CCW: The following 3 lines add dots to the chapter TOC listings
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
      \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unrelated: `epsfig` is totally obsolete (for  more than twenty years) and should be replaced with `\includegraphics`. Is there any reason not to use a toc package? You load  geometry, which certainly modifies the general layout.

Comment: You're loading `epstopdf` twice, by the way

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your reminder about the`epsfig` package. Other toc packages change the appearance of the table of content and I don't have time to change them back to the original design. I just need to increase the indents.

Comment: The chapter (for example) TOC entry is formatted by \l@chapter, so search MyThesisEnglish.cls for \l@chapter an modify accordingly.  Often these use \@dottedtocline where the indentation is the second argument.

Comment: And you probably don't need to load `epstopdf` at all unless you're using a really old version of TeX.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I found the way to increase the chapter title indention but don't know how to do the same change for sections and subsections. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Why the prohibition about using TOC pakages when you use many others? Do NOT change the code in any class or package without first giving it a new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ToC entries for `\chapter`s, `\section`s and `\subsection`s are handled by `\l@chapter`, `\l@section` and `\l@subsection`, respectively. Here are the definitions of each (from [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)):

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
```

Within `\l@chapter`, the length `\@tempdima` specifies the box width that holds the chapter number. The default definition, as you can see above, is `1.5em`. You can change this using the following

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{5.5em}{}{}
\makeatother
```

to increase the box width to `5.5em`, say.

Note how `\l@section`'s definition also uses `1.5em` as the first length parameter, followed by `2.3em`. The first length is the *indentation*, while the second length is the width of the box containing the section number. The first length in `\l@subsection` is `3.8em` (or `1.5em` + `2.3em`) and puts its number in a box of width `3.2em`. So it seems the indentation of the sub-level is the sum of the indentation of its parent level and the parent's box width. With this is mind, `\l@subsubsection` should have an indentation of `7em` (`3.8em` + `3.2em`):

```
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
```

Look at that!

You can change the `\section` and `\subsection` indentation to now coincide with your `5.5em` `\l@chapter` number-box width using

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{5.5em}{2.3em}{}{}% Since \l@chapter uses 5.5em for \@tempdima
\patchcmd{\l@subsection}{7.8em}{3.2em}{}{}% Since \l@section uses 5.5em + 2.3em
\makeatletter
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. 
`\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{5.5em}{}{}`
`\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{5.5em}{}{}`
`\patchcmd{\l@subsection}{3.8em}{7.8em}{}{}`
The only problem is that the chapter titles are long and when line breaks there is double-space gap between the first line and the second line of the chapter title. How to remove the extra space?

Comment: More info: https://imgur.com/a/Ex901

Comment: @R.Toward: That may be related to your use of `\addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{.5cm}}` before including every chapter. Perhaps try `\addtocontents{toc}{\par\addvspace{.5cm}}` (can't test it since I don't have your `\documentclass` or chapters).

Comment: Adding `\par` or removing the `{\addvspace{.5cm}}` doesn't affect the result. I have uploaded the cls file here. http://textuploader.com/dmdg6